# All the elements in my list gets removed when my program executes a new class

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a foreach loop that reads all the files in a folder and then splits it apart into smaller strings that will be put into a list called "fileImformation" and that will be put into a datagrid. I have checked out what's going on and it seems that the list just gets empty when executing

`DataContext = new FilePropertiesViewModel();`

**FilePropertiesViewModel code**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace RFAnalyzerMain
{
    public class FilePropertiesViewModel : MainWindow
    {
        public ICollectionView FileProperties { get; private set; }

        public FilePropertiesViewModel()
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempPathString);
            var _tarfiles = new List<TARFile>
            {
                new TARFile
                {
                    DataType = fileInformation[0],
                    VehicleIDUIC = fileInformation[1],
                    VehicleID = fileInformation[5],
                    Date = fileInformation[6],
                    Time = fileInformation[7],
                    ActionID = fileInformation[3],
                    RCFVer = fileInformation[8],
                    FileType = fileInformation[9],
                    FileName = fileInformation[10],
                    Size = fileInformation[11]
                }
            };


            FileProperties = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_tarfiles);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow code**

```
foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    fullFileName = file.ToString();

    stringVariables = fullFileName.Split('_');
    vehicleID = stringVariables[1].Substring(7, 4);
    dateAndTime = stringVariables[2].Split('-');
    splitFileTypeFromRCFVer = stringVariables[4].Split('.');

    
    FileInfo fileSizeNumbers = new FileInfo(fullFileName);
    fileSize = fileSizeNumbers.FullName.Length.ToString();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringVariables.Length; i++)
    {
        fileInformation.Add(stringVariables[i]);
    }
    fileInformation.Add(vehicleID);
    for (int i = 0; i < dateAndTime.Length; i++)
    {
        fileInformation.Add(dateAndTime[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < splitFileTypeFromRCFVer.Length; i++)
    {
        fileInformation.Add(splitFileTypeFromRCFVer[i]);
    }
    fileInformation.Add(fullFileName);
    fileInformation.Add(fileSize);
    DataContext = new FilePropertiesViewModel();
}
```

I've tried to put the DataContext code inside and outside as well but as soon as it enters the FilePropertiesViewModel Class the fileInformation list gets empty.

Comment: `class FilePropertiesViewModel : MainWindow` - a  view model class derived from MainWindow? That makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: `DataContext = new FilePropertiesViewModel();` this is creating a new `FilePropertiesViewModel` object and setting it as the DataContext. Your code doesn't show you doing anything with this new `FilePropertiesViewModel`.

Comment: @Clemens I'm very new to ViewModels, and I can't access the public fields in MainWindow with out

Comment: A view does not need to access fields in a view. Also, `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempPathString);` in the FilePropertiesViewModel constructor. How is that related to `di` in "MainWindow code"?

Comment: A viewmodel should be a separate class which doesn't inherit from anything view related. Usually.

Comment: @Andy okay so I should move those fields in MainWindow to a new class and implement that class in my ViewModel class?

Comment: It's a bad idea to put substantial code into any constructor. If it fails your class won't be constructed at all. This is particularly and sometimes spectacularly true for views.

Comment: Yep. Do simple first.

Comment: Textbox in the view string in a separate viewmodel class.

Comment: @Andy Okay thanks!

Comment: You will want a framework like mvvmlight or prism mvvm. But. Start with the very basics and implement inotifypropertychanged yourself. Plain properties first. Then bind an observablecollection to an itemscontrol itemssource and look at what collection changed does.

Comment: Can|t complete code that shows the context? This random snippets are annoying and impossible to understand for somebody who doesn't know what you are doing. You can tell this from the questions related to your code. To help you to fix a problem especially unexpected behavior requires to show the full context. You  must show all the initialization of shown locals, fields and properties. As already pointed out you need to rewrite you complete code - properly.

Comment: Microsoft Docs: [Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern), [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples), [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview)

Comment: I revote the whole code and it's working now! Just one issue, it creates an extra column at the left side of my datagrid. Not the extra white space column that fills up the right space. If anyone knows how to fix that it would be appreciated :)